# SVG markers showing through overlaid content (IE9)

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-9

Our application uses SVG to render a directed graph, using the `marker-end` attribute on `<path>` elements to display arrow heads for the direction. We are also using jQuery UI dialogs to present editable information about the graph to the user. The graph is rendered in a fairly large area on the page, so the dialogs display above the SVG content.

We have noticed that in IE9 (can't reproduce in any other browser) the arrow heads sometimes "bleed" through and are visible through parts of the dialog that is displayed over top of the SVG. These appear and disappear through clicking in various places on the dialog.

I have been unable to determine what is causing this, but it is quite reproducible. The effect can be seen [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/notkevinhart/jAvnC/). Click on the "click on this text!" text and the arrow head will bleed through in the red square. Clicking elsewhere and back on the text causes the arrow head to disappear and reappear.

This issue has been quite frustrating and I have been able to find nothing that would explain this behaviour.

**HTML**

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="-5 -5 30 30" refX="11" refY="9" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 0 0 L 14 9 L 0 18 z"></path>
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <path marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" d="M 30 30 H 100" style="stroke-width: 3px; stroke: #000;"></path>
</svg>
<div id="overlay">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>click on this text!</div>
</div>
<div id="ind"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;    
}
#overlay div {
    height: 20px;
}
#ind {
    position:absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 97px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    height:14px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any insights or help!

Comment: IS your fiddle correct?  I couldn't reproduce your issue with any of the browsers I tried (FF, Chrome, IE10).

Comment: @BigBadaboom The issue is only reproducible with IE9. (I put it in the title and tagged it with IE9, but I will edit the question to clarify.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the exact same problem. By accident, I found that a workaround is to set the opacity-style of the path element. So I modified the fiddle like this:

```
<path marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" d="M 30 30 H 100" 
style="stroke-width: 3px; stroke: #000; opacity:0.9999;">

</path>
```

It's not noticeably more transparent now but it somehow fixes the shine-through issue.

Comment: Unsure why this works, but it does! Thanks for the help.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` for `<svg>` (or it wrapper) also works fine for me. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23025480/1035113 for details.