# Click through "overlay"

Tags: html, css, overlay

Imagine this situation where I have:

This HTML

```
<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="content">
    <a href="">CAN THIS BE CLICKABLE IN ANY WAY? </a>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.content {position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:1; padding: 40px;}
.overlay {position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:2; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
```

Is there a way to make the div that is indexed behind the overlay "clickable" preferably without JavaScript?

Reason for this is that, I'd like to have an effect that covers the whole page but still permits the navigation and usage of content underneath.

Am I missing something, is there a way around... or is this not possible?

Thank you in advance.

[FIDDLE STARTUP](http://jsfiddle.net/5tGC7/)

**SOLUTION:** Check Bellow Please.

Addind this to inform that the solution has the following compatibility.

**Chrome - iOS - Android:** Yep
**Safari:** 4.0+
**Firefox:** 3.6+
**Opera:** 15.0+
**IE:** 9+

Comment: This is called a clickjacking when done in a malicious way. Please read up on the attack and browser attempts to protect against it to have a better idea of  why this behavior is not always safe or trusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `pointer-events: none;` to `.overlay`

See http://jsfiddle.net/iamnotsam/DV49T/1/ **uses SVG for IE9 and IE10 compatibility**

For IE 10, there is only partial support for `pointer-events: none`, specifically the element must be an svg. The above fiddle has been verified on one machine as making IE9 and IE10 happy. Thanks OP for testing.

Comment: +1 That works, but our beloved IE -10 wont. Any work around to older versions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also wait a minute I'm editing the jsfiddle to work with svg, unfortunately i won't be able to test it because i don't have ie10

Comment: Okay, see if that works. If it's that easy as other threads suggest, then I will be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that i think will help you. If you want the link to just be something to activate another element then use #Something to your link. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target

```
something:target
{}
```

Here is the lesson http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Here is yours updated http://jsfiddle.net/DrewGoldsberry/5tGC7/1/

This isnt working on jsfiddle but you can test at w3schools

Comment: I appreciate your answer and time, but I think You didn't understand exactly what I needed. The correct behavior is as explained in the question, and the marked as correct answer does exactly what I needed. Thank you anyway. Best.HC